# Skrollr: defining three animation keyframes

Tags: jquery, skrollr

I'm having a problem with Skrollr: I would like to define three states for an element. For example:

```
data-0="left: 0px"
data-500="left: 500px"
data-1000="left: 0px"
```

As I see it, one can only define a start and an end, which makes it impossible for me to reverse the animation, right?

Many thanks!

Comment: you can have as many keyframes as you want. What you posted works out of the box. http://jsbin.com/EsUFIQI/1

Comment: Thanks man, my bad! I actually need that for relative mode. Is there something like "data-top-bottom-500"? Many thanks again!

Comment: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#relative-mode-or-viewport-mode (hint: `[offset]`)